# Event at before email sent to user in Mail::send() in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I gone through the laravel documentations, I got  `Illuminate\Mail\Events\MessageSending` this event which is fired before sending emails.

Now I have created a listener for this event.

```
protected $listen = [
    'Illuminate\Mail\Events\MessageSending' => [
        'App\Listeners\IsSpamUser',
    ],
];
```

Now I am confused, In this Listener, How can I define that do not sent mail if user is spam.

Please Guide.

Answer (score 1):

As of Laravel 5.4.16, returning `false` from the `MessageSending` event handler will prevent the email from being sent.

However, in versions prior to 5.4.16, this event cannot be used to prevent sending the email (except by throwing an exception).